# How to Write Powershell Script for Removing Specific Tags in c# Project Files

Tags: regex, powershell, msbuild, nuget-package-restore, vcproj

I'm editing a Powershell script written by Owen Johnson on GitHub for migrating MSBuild-Integrated solutions to use Automatic Package Restore with Nuget. Here is the original migration script:

```
########################################
# Regex Patterns for Really Bad Things!
$listOfBadStuff = @(
    #sln regex
    "\s*(\.nuget\\NuGet\.(exe|targets)) = \1",
    #*proj regexes
    "\s*<Import Project=""\$\(SolutionDir\)\\\.nuget\\NuGet\.targets"".*?/>",
    "\s*<Target Name=""EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports"" BeforeTargets=""PrepareForBuild"">(.|\n)*?</Target>"
    "\s*<RestorePackages>\w*</RestorePackages>"
)

#######################
# Delete NuGet.targets

ls -Recurse -include 'NuGet.exe','NuGet.targets' |
  foreach { 
    remove-item $_ -recurse -force
    write-host deleted $_
}

#########################################################################################
# Fix Project and Solution Files to reverse damage done by "Enable NuGet Package Restore

ls -Recurse -include *.csproj, *.sln, *.fsproj, *.vbproj, *.wixproj, *.vcxproj |
  foreach {
    sp $_ IsReadOnly $false
    $content = cat $_.FullName | Out-String
    $origContent = $content
    foreach($badStuff in $listOfBadStuff){
        $content = $content -replace $badStuff, ""
    }
    if ($origContent -ne $content)
    {   
        $content | out-file -encoding "UTF8" $_.FullName
        write-host messed with $_.Name
    }           
}
```

I want to also remove `<Target>` tags and their contents where Name= "EnsureBclBuildImported". I'm not very experienced with regular expressions, and my initial attempts to get this to work have failed unfortunately. I tried changing the regex for the target tag to be `"\s*<Target Name=""(EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports|EnsureBclBuildImported)""/.+?(?=>)/(.|\n)*?</Target>"`
I also tried making a new regualar expression like this: `"\s*<Target Name=""EnsureBclBuildImported"" ^[^\>]*(.|\n)*?</Target>"`

Comment: I'm not sure what your file contents look like, but I think if you  change your `.+?` to a `.*?`, remove all but the last forward slash, and then escape the last forward slash, it should work. Check this [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/oO1zW3/1) link to see if that works for you.

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what I did. Here is the expression that worked for me: `"\s*<Target Name=""(EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports|EnsureBclBuildImported)""(.|\n)*?>(.|\n)*?</Target>"`